# Displaying � instead of ü in angular2 post request

Tags: web-services, angular, utf-8, angular2-services

I have facing issue in displaying German Umlaut characters in HTML page of angular2 application.
My backend services are in java and it returns json String.

This is the response of the post request which is shown in network tab. and it shows ü character properly .

[image]

but if i console the data from below snippet, it shows � both in HTML ui and console .

```
    getStackById(project: string, stackId: string, ibsessionid: string) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this.http.post('http://' + this.ip + ':' + this.port + '/IBPublicationBuilder/MiddlewareServlet', 'project=' + project + '&stackid=' + stackId + '&ibsessionid=' + ibsessionid + '&method=getStackById', {
      withCredentials: true, headers: headers
    }).map(
      (res: Response) => {
         console.log(res);
        return res.json()}
      );
  }
```

console:[image]

UI: 
[image]

Comment: plz help.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with the below solution.

Added

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');
```

In the header and also Changed the server side.
As I mentioned my services were in java . 
Added

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

to my my response object.

Comment: But incase there is any solution in which i can change only front end and solve the issue, then please let me know